# How to crete New Web Service inside moodle?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am go through the service module inside moodle , how can i add my own function and class for handling some operations such as enrolling and register . is it possible or not

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new plugin (probably a 'local' plugin) and add a webservice within it:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_a_web_service_to_a_plugin

Comment: I am created new service inside service module . created callback function inside corresponding class . inside the class file created function , parameters and its return function .Then i am accessing through the url it gives the error like     {"exception":"dml_missing_record_exception","errorcode":"invalidrecord","message"
:"Can not find data record in database table external_functions."}

Answer (score 0):

this might help

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

even this---
https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Using_web_services

Comment: Nishil my question is about how to expand service.php inside moodle webservice section, I want to create new API for handling some sections in moodle , so is there any way to do this. Custom service creation or Custom API Creation

Answer (score 0):

I created a new web service "core_completion_override_course_completion_status"

1. Duplicate any existing web service and replace the words as per your need in the method name, class name etc.

Increate Moodle main version from version.php in root moodle folder.